# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Copy Texture Data

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an array of 2D textures initialized in OpenGL ES 2.0:

```
textures[10];
```

After I delete one of the textures at a given array index:

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &textures[5]);
```

How do I remove the empty gap left in my array, with relative ease, in order to keep things neat and tidy? Is there a more direct method other than rendering each texture and then using `glGetTexImage` as a way to change the order of the textures in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textures array is actually an array of 'names' represented by non-zero integers set by `glGenTextures` that represent texture locations on the GPU. As long as you keep track of the valid textures names and what your using them for you can sort the array any way you want.

Comment: It seems to me that you may want to leave this as a comment.

Comment: I can't comment on his question because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @user3839254 Would something as simple sorting the names by textures[5] = textures[6] work correctly?

Comment: Yes, you can slide all the remaining names down to fill the gap from the texture that was deleted.

Comment: @hicklc01 nice, much simpler than I thought it would be